# Communicate with RTMP server with C++ or Objective C application

Tags: c++, objective-c, streaming, rtmp, communication-protocol

Is it possible communicate with rtmp server with C++ or Objective C application, like flash player do this ?
i know it must be possible because flash player was written on C++ and use C++ library. if you know how do this pleas show me code exemple !
Thank for any help!

Comment: For future readers: RTMP was created by Macromedia, now owned by Adobe. ActionScript is primarily used for building flash applications and therefore have support for RTMP. At the time of writing, i'm unsure of what language Flash, ActionScript, etc, was built in, but i suspect C++ or C (probably the latter). I would also assume that they have their own RTMP implementation and not using librtmp. The spec was not disclosed for a LONG time, and the spec is not very good either.

Answer (score 5):

[librtmp](http://rtmpdump.mplayerhq.hu/librtmp.3.html) is a C library for building rtmp clients/servers. It is usable from C++ and Objective C.